# android - Как юзать сom.android.internal.telephony?

Tags: android

Делаю приложение для разлочки (разблокировки от оператора связи). Мне нужно найти способ как овладеть методами интерфейсов и классов `Phone`, `RIL`, `IccCard`. Импорт `com.android.internal.telephony.*;` сделать не получается, так как этой директории нет в `SDK`. Замечал, что системные приложения используют эти импорты, как их заполучить в обычном приложении? Мне нужно довести разлочку до **автоматизма** - мне нужен метод `supplyNetworkDepersonalization`, который на вход принимает два `String` и `Handler`. Этот метод находится в интерфейсе `IccCard` и просто так к нему не подойти. На поиск информации убито полгода и безрезультатно.

Со временем пришлось использовать метод `getSimSerialNumber()`, который возвращает `Icc` код SIM-карты. Стало интересно, как же он это делает, ведь этот код знает лишь модем. Открыл его в гитхабе и опять увидел эти импорты `com.android.internal.telephony`. Ну, неужели, никак нельзя осуществить это? Помогите идеями, надоело мозг ломать. Приложение будет работать с правами `root`, так что солюшны с его участием предлагайте тоже))

Если использовать рефлексию, то я не знаю как передавать параметры методам, да еще и получать возвращаемое значение